# TextField either phone number or Email format validation swift?

Tags: ios, swift, validation

I having one text field for forgot password ,here user enter either mobile number or email then we send OTP to that.

I am trying to validations for that text field with my code but it is not working, any one give some idea on that please find my code with following.

It needs to valid for either mailid or Phone number format.

```
if emaiTF.text == "" {
            print("Enter either valid phone or email")
        }else if let validphone = emaiTF.text, validphone.isValidPhone() || validphone.isValidEmail() {
            print("Enter either valid phone or email")
        }else{
            forGotPasswordApi()
        }
```

my validation methods like following.

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        // here, `try!` will always succeed because the pattern is valid
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
    }

    // vrify Valid PhoneNumber or Not
    func isValidPhone() -> Bool {

        let phoneRegex = "^[0-9]{10}$";
        let valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex).evaluate(with: phoneRegex)
        return valid
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified and added your code patch in below answer. Please check and if it works for you then do accept so other can take benefits of it!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the problem in your output validation. Modified your code in following way to work, please validate.

```
  extension ViewController {

    func checkValidation() {
      if txtUserName.text == "" {
          print("Enter either valid phone or email 1")
      } else if let validphone = txtUserName.text, validphone.isValidPhone() || validphone.isValidEmail() {
          print("Success")
          forGotPasswordApi()
      }else{
        print("Enter either valid phone or email 2")
      }
    }
  }

  extension String {
      func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
          // here, `try!` will always succeed because the pattern is valid
          let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let valid = regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
        print("Email validation \(valid)")
          return valid
      }

      // vrify Valid PhoneNumber or Not
      func isValidPhone() -> Bool {

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]\\d{9}$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let valid = regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
        print("Mobile validation \(valid)")
          return valid
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

My Validation is:

```
extension String {

var isValidEmail: Bool {
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}").evaluate(with: self)
}
 var numberValidation: Bool {
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[0-9]).{10}$").evaluate(with: self)
  }
}
```

My code for checking give input

```
if mailTextField.text!.isValidEmail {
        print("u have entered correct mail format")
    }
if phonenumber.text!.numberValidation {
 print("mobile number in correct format")
}
```

Comment: You are not even checking if the string is a valid phone number

Comment: I didn't get you point. Can you please tell once again clearly(as am new contributor), if you don't mean?

Comment: If you didn't get why did you edit your answer and added the phone number condition as well ? Btw as I already commented on the other posts. **UITextField text property will never return nil. It’s default value is an empty string.** you can simply force unwrap its result `if mailTextField.text!.isValidEmail {`

Comment: sure, thank you for value contribution on my comment.

Comment: `== true` is redundant you can simply omit it if your string it is not optional anymore

Answer (score 0):

Phone Number Validation

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted

    let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)

    let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")

    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }

    let count = text.count + string.count - range.length

    return string == numberFiltered && count <= 10

  }
```

Comment: OP uses the same field for phone number or email. You can’t simply discard any non digits from the Textfield contents. BTW Why don’t you simply filter your unwanted characters ? `string.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }` another point is `joined(separator: "")` is pointless just use `joined()`

Comment: `UITextField` text property will never return `nil`. It’s default value is an empty string. Your guard will never enter the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Email Validation

Pass your string in the below method

The Below Method will return Bool Value YES or NO

Method :

```
 func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Usage :

```
if isValidEmail(testStr: emailTxtFld.text!) == True {

       print("Valid");        
 }
else {

    print("In Valid");
 }
```

Comment: isValidEmail Method takes a non optional string. You would need to unwrap your string when calling that method `emailTxtFld.text`. BTW `== true` is redundant. `if isValidEmail(testStr: emailTxtFld.text!) {`

Comment: What is the reason to add 2 answers? You can update the previously added answer.

Comment: `True` it is not a type. Again `== true` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code you've provided a little bit by changing the validation checks. I think `validInput.isValidPhone() || validInput.isValidEmail()` is not handled right on your code.

```
// Check if any input is entered and not empty string
guard let validInput = emaiTF.text, validInput != "" else {
  print("Enter either valid phone or email")
  return
}

// Check if entered value is valid or not
if validInput.isValidPhone() || validInput.isValidEmail() { 
  forGotPasswordApi()
} else {
  print("Enter either valid phone or email")
}
```

Comment: `UITextField` text property will never return `nil`. It’s default value is an empty string. Btw you can simply use `UIKeyInput` property called `hasText` To check if the field is empty or not

Comment: @LeoDabus I just wanted to add the same checks as the person who asked the question.

Comment: `guard emaiTF.hasText else {` and `if emaiTF.text!.isValidPhone() || emaiTF.text!.isValidEmail() { `